# Apache redirect to https if the request is not from localhost

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, https, rewrite, virtual-host

I have a Centos 6.7 with apache 2.2.15. I want to redirect all traffic from port 80 to 443 with one exception. The traffic who come from localhost I want to remain on port 80.

Now I use this config but I don't know how to change it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `RewriteCond` with `%{REMOTE_ADDR}`, possibly multiple to deal with if you have IPv6 enabled or not. This is the basic config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

[Here is a tutorial on using RewriteCond that might be some help](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/rewrite/).

Comment: Thanks! It's work but only for request like this http:// localhost. If the request is like this http:// 127.0.0.1 doesn't work. How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: As I said you may need to add a few `RemoteCond`s to deal with all cases. The way to see why specific cases are not working is using an Apache log file with `LogFormat` containing the vars you are using in your conditions, or write some server content in PHP (or whatever your preferred server side tech is) that outputs what the variables are for a specific request.